# lost multiple id javascript faceOut in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you press 'Enter' in the input this create a textbox tag with a id.
But if i send too many text, the text stop in time.

I think is because multiple id´s but the console logs are ok

```
var num_texto = 0;
var div_text = $('#div_text');

function speak(txt) {
    var id_text = 'texto_'.concat(numtext);
    var html = div_text.innerHTML;
    html = html.concat("<textbox id='" + id_text + "' class='textbox'>" + txt + "</textbox>");
    div_text.innerHTML = html;
    numtext++;
    console.log('id = ' + id_text);
    setTimeout(function (id_text) {
        console.log(id_text);
        $("#" + id_text).fadeOut(500);
    }, 1000, id_text);
}
```

Comment: So you have multiple elements with the same id?

Comment: I have something like texto_0,texto_1,texto_2

Comment: Ok not enough information here, I'm even unclear what you're asking. Can you explicitly ask what you're stuck on and include any more relevant code/markup?

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1> Here is a fiddle,</h1>
```

[### Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saifudazzlings/bem06dcp/1/)

``
    Please check it, i've done this fiddle by using what i understand from your question. I hope it will help you.